# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Japanese Language's [third moderator election](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: Chocolate]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5699181213646848/0).

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations and a warm welcome from the moderator team. I'm certain @Chocolate will be doing fantastic job (also) as moderator!

Comment: おおっ　ありがとうございます！　よろしくお願いします　<m(_ _)m>

Answer (score 3):

@Jon Ericson I also applied. Unfortunately I wasn't even notified that I hadn't gotten the position. Given that I invested a good deal of time answering the questions and taking part in the process, I think the least I deserved was for someone to take 5 seconds to ping me so I got a notification about it.

Comment: First of all thank you for standing for election! In a small election like this a ping might have been nice, but  I guess it would be reasonable to expect candidates to take a note of the end date and check the outcome whenever they can find the time.